# How to know if my file is inserted correctly `glyphtounicode`

Tags: packages, miktex, font-encodings, copy-paste, pdfx

In several suggestions for making pdflatex output copy-and-pasteable, is part of the suggestion to insert the code,

```
\input glyphtounicode.tex
\pdfgentounicode=1
\pdfcompresslevel=0
```

TeXstudio marks in red that this file `glyphtounicode` does not exist in my `.tex` document directory. But I found the file in the MikTex directory. My question is, how do I really know that the file is being inserted?

In addition, I also insert the following code,

```
\usepackage[a-2b,mathxmp]{pdfx}[2018/12/22]
\InputIfFileExists{glyphtounicode-cmr.tex}{}{} 
\InputIfFileExists{glyphtounicode-ntx.tex}{}{}
```

The `glyphtounicode-` files are in the `pdfx` package folder, are they also being inserted correctly?

**Additional information:** I'm using `pdflatex` on TeXstudio on *Windows*.

Comment: Does the `mmap` package help you?

Comment: Does either file show up in your output log?

Comment: You would get errors if input doesn't find a file. And you  can an unknown command (eg \unknown)  to the third argument of \InputIfFileExists to get an error too if it fails.

Comment: @Davislor True, I had forgotten about the `.log` file, which contains information about the packages and files included. Thank you.